# How to generate nswag file from OpenAPI spec using NSwag CLI on Mac?

Tags: command-line-interface, nswag

On my Mac, I want to generate `.nswag` file from OpenAPI spec. i.e., I can simply put this, `https://www.test.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json`, on NSwagStudio (windows app) and it will generate `.nswag` file.

I do not know how to that via CLI. What is the command for that?

Once I have `.nsawg` file, then I can use `nswag run /runtime:NET60 MySpec.nswag` to generate client, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

1. First create a `console app` project and add `NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp` package to it.
2. Then provide `swagger.json` path and the `path for saving` the generated client to a function like this :

```
async static Task GenerateClient(string url, string generatePath)
{
var document=await OpenApiDocument.FromUrlAsync(url);
var settings = new CSharpClientGeneratorSettings
{
    ClassName = "MyClass", 
    CSharpGeneratorSettings = 
    {
        Namespace = "MyNamespace"
    }
};

var generator = new CSharpClientGenerator(document, settings);  
var code = generator.GenerateFile();

await System.IO.File.WriteAllTextAsync(generatePath, code);

}
```

This should generate client.cs file for you.